# SSL Read Error when making an API call from R Shinny App

Tags: api, shiny

I needed some help on the below error which i receive while doing a Http POST call t an API in cloud.
I am using the httr in my shiny app to make this call.

Error: *  SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 110
*  Connection died, retrying a fresh connect
*  Closing connection 18

If anyone has faced a same/similar error and can share some details or any leads to the right direction for investigation.

Thanks
Vinish

Comment: Can you provide code of your current call. Easier to help that way.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for response. Below is the POST call made:  POST(URL
                    , authenticate(username, pwd)
                    , body = Data_Json
, content_type(".json")
, verbose(data_out = TRUE, data_in = TRUE, info = TRUE)
#, add_headers(Expect = ‘’) # to tackle Expect:100
)